Somebody used recommendation by an in-law – should I report it?
I recently learned that a friend of mine was accepted in their master’s program to become a therapist after multiple denials throughout the past years. They tried again this year with an additional recommendation and finally got in. They shared that one of their letters of recommendation was submitted by their in-law, a counselor, whom they listed as their mentor.
I just do not feel like this is right and am torn between reporting it or just not saying anything. They don’t feel as if they did anything wrong and to be honest I’m not sure if they did because I’m not up to date with these kind of things but it doesn’t sound right.
Any insight on what I should do would be appreciated.

What is your relationship to these two people? What is your relationship to the university?

How do you know that their in-law did not disclose the nature of their relationship?

@wrzlprmft: not sure about the "without disclosure" part in the title; that does not seem to be established.

@cag51: I interpreted “listed as their mentor” as this, but yeah, strictly speaking the asker doesn’t know and should clarify. Anyway, the entire question becomes moot with disclosure, so for answers there is little difference between no disclosure or unknown disclosure.

@cag51 this previous revision says "The individual also mentioned that the familial relationship was not disclosed in the letter, and they advised altering the last name on the application and social media accounts to avoid any apparent connection. According to them, this was within guidelines."

@muru Good find. I wonder why that key information was removed. Buffy's answer makes a lot more sense with this context.

I'm -1, as the asker edited out relevant details.

There is probably nothing to do here. A "mentor" is not a formally-defined thing, and if their in-law is involved enough to write a letter of recommendation, the term "mentor" seems like an apt moniker.
The mentor should have disclosed the relationship in their letter of recommendation. If they didn't, that is likely a breach of ethics on the recommender's part. But, for all you know, they did disclose it and there is no issue. Even if they didn't, there is no reason to think that the recommendee did anything wrong. Even if the recommendee did do something wrong, getting their admission rescinded at this point would probably require evidence of "gross misconduct" (such as if they were specifically asked about recommenders who were family members and they lied about it).
Unless you have a lot more information that you didn't share with us above, it seems like involving yourself in this is much more likely to ruin your relationship with your "friend" than it is to correct an injustice.

As in-law is rather broad, the severity of this conflict of interest can broadly range from the recommender being slightly more welcome at family reunions to ensuring the future of recommender’s child who is the recommendee’s spouse.
Given that you asked this question, I assume that the conflict is on the severe end of the spectrum.
In general, there is strong consensus that letters of recommendation from close relatives are a bad idea and problematic, see, e.g., this, this and this question and the references therein.
The easiest solution would be if  the school explicitly states what degrees of relationship must be disclosed in recommendations or completely preclude them, so I recommend to check this before anything else.
If they don’t, this might be one of those things which is easier to navigate over a phone call to the admissions office (or similar):
You first describe the situation as if asking for yourself, and ask whether it would be problematic.
Only if it is, you continue to inform them about your friend.
That way, you can also ensure your anonymity as much as desired (which should be no problem since they have to independently verify your claims anyway).
You have to eventually sort out the ethics and your allegiance to your friend yourself, but here are a few considerations:

It is not upon you to decide whether there is a problem, but on the school:
If they decide that all is fine, you’ve done whatever duty you could possibly have.
The one thing you can do wrong here is to waste their time with frivolous hints (which I assume you don’t).

If the school acts upon your report, what happened likely was actually problematic.

Places in the school are probably limited, so while your report might thwart your friend’s career, it also enables somebody else’s.



Well, it certainly isn't right. And deception in a therapist seems a bit dangerous. More than a bit, actually. The in-law has also acted unprofessionally. Would you trust either of them with important personal matters?
But, raising the issue with the university will likely affect your relationship with the person if the university acts on your complaint, which they might not. If they act, they might not be able to hold your communication in confidence. But it is unlikely that they would or could act on an anonymous complaint.
People can change, however, and the masters program might have a positive effect on that person's attitudes about what is right and wrong. I don't have high confidence in that, however.
Whether you act or not might depend on what you might know about why they were denied entry previously, and on what you know about their general ethical behavior or lack of it. You do suggest that there was also deception involved.

I doubt that a university would/could act on an anonymous complaint. You would probably need to be known to them. Whether they reveal your name depends on a lot of things, including legal issues.

"it is unlikely that they would or could act on an anonymous complaint" -- why? In this case it does not require trusting the source of the complaint. All the pertinent facts (the contents of the recommendation, and the fact that the writer was related to the applicant) are independently verifiable by the university if they care to look into it. An anonymous note would just be bringing their attention to these facts. If the info is wrong, or if there are mitigating factors unknown to OP, then the university can disregard. ...

... If universities impose a policy of never acting on anonymous tips even when there is evidence  that does not depend on trusting the veracity of the tipster, then they should realize that they will miss important issues due to reluctance to report with a name attached for exactly the reasons you cite.

@nanoman, anonymous complaints are hard to act on as the recipient of the complaint has no way to judge motive of the complainer. And, they might also find it hard to discern the truth of it if people have been lying to them already. "Just who is lying to us here" might be impossible to know. Hence, reluctance, at least, about accepting anonymous complaints unless they come with hard evidence.

I am suggesting that in this case the motive of someone flagging the issue is (or should be) irrelevant -- either the recommendation violated the rules or it didn't. You say "unless they come with hard evidence" -- are you thinking that somehow OP is the only possible source that can attest to how the recommender and applicant were related? It seems likely that in a note, OP could helpfully point the university to publicly available documentation that indicates a relationship between these two people, at least at a level of plausibility that would justify further investigation.
